# Matching any integral type in a C# 8.0 switch expression

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

So, I am doing this to create a class (ClassX) from an object when any integral type that converts to a decimal would be an acceptable parameter:

```
    var mp = argument switch
    {
        ClassX p => p,
        string s => new ClassX( s ),
        byte b => new ClassX( Convert.ToDecimal( b ) ),
        short h => new ClassX( Convert.ToDecimal( h ) ),
        ushort t => new ClassX( Convert.ToDecimal( t ) ),
        int n => new ClassX( Convert.ToDecimal( n ) ),
        uint u => new ClassX( Convert.ToDecimal( u ) ),
        long g => new ClassX( Convert.ToDecimal( g ) ),
        ulong o => new ClassX( Convert.ToDecimal( o ) ),
        double d => new ClassX( Convert.ToDecimal( d ) ),
        float f => new ClassX( Convert.ToDecimal( f ) ),
        decimal m => new ClassX( m ),
        _ => ClassX.empty
    };
```

but I don't think this really checks if the conversion succeeds (plus it is way wordy.)
(I know I can stick the TryParse as a condition into each case but it is even more way wordy.)

I would like to do this (my ClassX has an Empty) but it never matches the TryParse and always returns Empty.

```
var mp = argument switch
{
    ClassX p => p,
    string s => new ClassX( s ),
    _ when decimal.TryParse( argument.ToString(), out decimal v ) => new ClassX( v ),
    _ => ClassX.Empty
};
```

Is there a way to make this syntax work? Why is the 'when' being ignored?

Update: because I don't want to hide my confusion.

Notice that just about everything is IConvertible so you must attempt a conversion. My problem with the struct was not a problem directly with the struct but the 2nd version I edited dropped the string parameter and the struct did not support this. So, if this is useful, this is my only sensible solution (after adding a constructor that will take just a decimal):

```
var mp = argument switch {
    ClassX p => p,
    IConvertible d when decimal.TryParse( d.ToString(), out var v ) => 
        new ClassX( v ),
    _ => ClassX.Empty 
}
```

Comment: *"but I don't think this really checks if the conversion succeeds "* -- the `Convert.ToDecimal` calls should throw if the fail, no?

Comment: Yes - I'll grant that (even tho I don't want to fail!) but my interest is in matching ANY INTEGRAL TYPE (without having to list every one of them,)

Comment: `Convert.ToDecimal(object)` already has logic to check whether a type can be converted to a decimal, so I'd just use that? No point in re-inventing the wheel. That or use `IConvertible` directly: `(argument as IConvertible)?.ToDecimal(null)`, and catch the `FormatException`. That does the same as `Convert.ToDecimal(object)`, the difference being that you'll get `null` if that type doesn't implement `IConvertible`, rather than an `InvalidCastException`. [See here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,5325a06d0a430033)

Comment: What is the `argument` type?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski it has to be `object` (or I suppose `IComparable` or `IConvertible`): nothing else will compile

Comment: @TerrierJack in which actual cases then `when` clause does not work for you? `object argument = 5` seems to be working just fine.

Comment: @canton7 the second OP example is also not compile, based on code `ClassX` has constructor with `decimal` and `string` parameters or `string` only, not the  single `decimal` parameter. Therefore I'm asking for type of argument and entire code sample

Comment: I have several constructors - that is beside the point. How do I match on any integral without listing every single type separately? (Just imagine I have 2 constructors - one takes a string and the other takes a decimal.)

Comment: @TerrierJack by testing for `IConvertible` and using that, like I said

Comment: Ah! I'll crawl away now (didn't write the class) and noticed it was NOT a class. It is a struct. The simplified version does not work for a struct. Now my question is why should that be?

Comment: Can you update your question to match your latest attempts and knowledge?